# Sum up the values of a html table column using a for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, for-loop

I have a HTML table with 2 columns, which get updated by an `ajax php` query. This all works fine but I want to sum up the right column `(Your Calories)` every time the table gets a new entry.

For the total value, I created a new table with just one row and two columns.

The first time I click the add button, the total is 0 although there is already a value in the "Your Calories" column. If I add a second line to the table, it returns me the value of the first entry. If I add a third line to the table, it sums up the first and the second line. So there is always one line missing and I don't get why...

---

This is my html code:

```html
<input id="food" name="food" value="Choose your Food">
<input id="amount" value="Choose the amount in gram" name="amount">
<input type="button" value="Add" id="submit" name="submit" />

<div id="update_div">
<table id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <th>Your Food</th>
    <th>Your Calories</th>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>

<table>
   <tr>
    <td>Your Total</td>
    <td id="total"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

My javascript code:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function() {


        <!-- WORKS FINE SO FAR -->

        var food = $("#food").val();
        var amount = $("#amount").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'search_value.php?food='+ food + '&amount='+amount,
            type: 'GET',
            datatype: "html",   
            success: function(data)
            {
                $('#update_div table').append(data);
            },
        });

        <!-- THIS IS THE PART, WHICH DOES NOT WORK CORRECTLY -->

        var sum = 0;
        var table = document.getElementById("mytable");
        var ths = table.getElementsByTagName('th');
        var tds = table.getElementsByTagName('td');
        for(var i=0;i<tds.length;i++){
            sum += isNaN(tds[i].innerText) ? 0 : parseInt(tds[i].innerText);
        }
        document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = sum;

    });
});
```

---

And my PHP code:

```html
<?php
    //database configuration
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=calotools', 'root', '');

    $food = $_GET['food'];
    $amount = $_GET['amount'];

    $query="SELECT * FROM nahrungsmittel WHERE name = '$food'";

    $user = $pdo->query($query)->fetch();
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$user['name']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$user['kcal'] / 100 * $amount."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
?>
```

---

Maybe you guys see the problem? I don't know if this is the best practice to sum up a column by their values but this was the only way it worked for me so far.

Comment: ajax is asynchronous. Can't do the calculation until the data is inserted withiin the success handler

Comment: Alright. So I think I have to create a button to add the entry and one more for sum up the column.

Comment: No.. you need to do sum after the data is received and inserted. Put that code inside `success` and after `append`

Comment: Ah nice. Works perfectly! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works by putting the "sum-up-code" inside the success handler. Thanks to charlietfl!

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        var food = $("#food").val();
        var amount = $("#amount").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'search_value.php?food='+ food + '&amount='+amount,
            type: 'GET',
            datatype: "html",   
            success: function(data)
            {
                $('#update_div table').append(data);

                var sum = 0;
                var table = document.getElementById("mytable");
                var ths = table.getElementsByTagName('th');
                var tds = table.getElementsByTagName('td');
                for(var i=0;i<tds.length;i++){
                    sum += isNaN(tds[i].innerText) ? 0 : parseInt(tds[i].innerText);
                }
                document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = sum;
            },
        });
});
```